# After adding a non-case sensitive search and clickable pictures, script stopped working

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to make my first project with bunch of pictures, with a filter/search bar at the top that would filter the pictures depending on the input. For example if the input would be "Aatrox", it would show "Aatrox" and not "Jayce" and or "Senna" and so on. Script was working fine, I added a .toLowerCase() so its not case sensitive and then I added  to the pictures so they are clickable and each lead to their own page. After adding these two the search bar stopped working.

Here is the snippet of the script

```
        <script>
            function search(){
                var searchText = (document.getElementById("searchInput").value).toLowerCase();
                var images = document.querySelectorAll(".image_container > img");
          
                if(searchText.length > 0){
                    images.forEach((image) => {
                        image.classList.add("hide");
                        if((image.dataset.tags).toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) > -1){
                            image.classList.remove("hide");
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    images.forEach((image) => {
                        image.classList.remove("hide");
                    });
                }
            }
        </script>
```

Here is the HTML part

```
<head>
        <title> Counterpicks </title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1> Counterpicks pro debily </h1>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="searchbox_container">
                <div class="searchbox">
                    <input type="text" name=" " placeholder="Search" class="search" id="searchInput" onkeyup="search()">
                </div>
            </div>


         <div class="image_container">
            <a href="aatrox.html"><img data-tags="aatrox" src="aatrox.webp" alt="Aatrox" class="actionimages"></a>
            <a href="ahri.html"><img data-tags="ahri" src="ahri.webp" alt="Ahri" class="actionimages"></a>
         </div>
```

I input only few of the lines because they are just repeating for 130 lines.

And here is the CSS

```
.container {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
}

.searchbox {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  
.image_container {
    clear:both;
}
  
  
.hide {
  display:none;
```

This is my first project with JavaScript so I will be happy for any constructive criticism.

Comment: The problem is `document.querySelectorAll(".image_container > img")`. You don't have any direct child images in `image_container`. Remove the > and it works

Answer (score -1):

Replace:

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll(".image_container > img");
```

with:

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll(".image_container > a > img");
```